# Python3 - Append each character to a string (making a line)

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an XML element, that looks like this:

**XML**

```
<page>
    <textline id="1">
        <text>C</text>
        <text>o</text>
        <text>n</text>
        <text>t</text>
        <text>a</text>
        <text>k</text>
        <text>t</text>
    </textline>
    <textline id="2">
        <text>
        </text>
    </textline>
    <textline id="3">
        <text>M</text>
        <text>e</text>
    </textline>
</page>
```

I am trying to get **all** the `<textline>` tags **only**:

```py
with open(path_to_xml_file) as xml_file:    
     parsed_xml = BeautifulSoup(xml_file, 'xml')
     text_lines = parsed_xml.find_all("textline")
```

However, `text_lines` includes all children of `<textline>` - which means it includes all the `<text></text>` tags.

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that explains how to only select the actual tag (and not any children, sub children etc.).

I found the `recursive=False` option, which should only select *direct* children, so I thought I could apply this to the `page` tag:

```
text_lines = parsed_xml.find_all("page", recursive=False)
```

But that returns an empty list: `[]`

## Expected result:

```
<textline id="1"></textline>
<textline id="2"></textline>
<textline id="3"></textline>
```

Comment: What's your expected result ? If you don't mind having the children you could try to count the `textline` tags maybe.

Comment: what is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: Hi both - just updated my original post with the expected result.

Comment: I think BeautifulSoup can't open file - it needs text with html/xml instead of filename. Or you have to use `open()`  -  `BeautifulSoup(open('myXMLfile.xml'), 'xml')` - see [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `string=''`

**Ex:**

```
xml = """<page>
<textline id="1">
  <text>C</text>
  <text>o</text>
  <text>n</text>
  <text>t</text>
  <text>a</text>
  <text>k</text>
  <text>t</text>
</textline>
<textline id="2">
  <text>
  </text>
</textline>
<textline id="3">
  <text>M</text>
  <text>e</text>
</textline>
</page>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
parsed_xml = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
text_lines = []
for tag in parsed_xml.find_all("textline"):
    tag.string = ''
    text_lines.append(tag)
print(text_lines)
```

**Output:**

```
[<textline id="1"></textline>,
 <textline id="2"></textline>,
 <textline id="3"></textline>]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **clear()** method to remove all the inside `<text>` tags from `<textline>` tags,

one more thing you can't send file name to **BeautifulSoup**, you have to open it and send the content to it, here I kept xml content in a variable.

```
myxml = """<page>
<textline id="1">
  <text>C</text>
  <text>o</text>
  <text>n</text>
  <text>t</text>
  <text>a</text>
  <text>k</text>
  <text>t</text>
</textline>
<textline id="2">
  <text>
  </text>
</textline>
<textline id="3">
  <text>M</text>
  <text>e</text>
</textline>
</page>"""

parsed_xml = BeautifulSoup(myxml, 'xml')
text_lines = parsed_xml.find_all("textline")
for tl in text_lines:
    tl.clear()

print(text_lines)
```

**Output:**

```
[<textline id="1"/>, <textline id="2"/>, <textline id="3"/>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I originally tagged this question with `beautifulsoup`, but I just wanted to share what I actually ended up using. The solution from **@Rakesh** does works with beaufitulsoup.

I actually ended up using Pythons built-in XML parser:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(path_to_xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for textline in root.iter('textline'):
    print(textline)
```

I think this is a much cleaner solution - so hopefully this can help anyone comign across this post.